# Get access to the last yielded state within the Flutter BloC

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have two screens: first one is list of items and second is the form page for editing or creating items. Each page is managed via dedicated BloC - `ItemListBloc` and `FormBloc` respectively, using `flutter_bloc` library. Whenever the submit is called on the Form I want to react to this in `ItemListBloc` and modify or insert item in the list to avoid refetching whole thing from the backend.

This is how I try to achieve this:

```
  ItemListBloc({ @required this.itemFormBloc, ... }) {
    itemFormSub = itemFormBloc.state.listen((state) {
      if (state is FormSubmitted) {
        dispatch(ModifyOrInsert(isEdit: state.isEdit, item: state.isItem));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Stream<ItemListState> mapEventToState(
    ItemListEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is ModifyOrInsert) {
      yield* _modifyOrInsert(isEdit: event.isEdit, item: event.item);
    }
  }

  Stream<ItemListState> _modifyOrInsert({bool isEdit, Item item}) async* {
    // How to get access to the list of items here?
  }
```

Unlike Redux-y global state I have number of states which I can manipulate and declare one of them current. The last state of `ItemListBloc` is typically `ItemsLoaded` which holds the whole items list. I need to get access to this state, take items, update item in list if it was an edit, prepend item to the list if it was create and silently `yield` updated `ItemsLoaded` state afterwards.